# NextJS npm run dev looking for .next folder in docker build. .next folder does not exist

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, next.js, dockerfile

I have a docker compose setup to run my NextJS app in development.  It was working fine and I'm not sure what changed.  When the Docker image runs the npm run dev command I receive this error:

> nti-web-web-1  | ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
> nti-web-web-1  | [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/.next/package.json'] {
> nti-web-web-1  |   errno: -13,
> nti-web-web-1  |   code: 'EACCES',
> nti-web-web-1  |   syscall: 'open',
> nti-web-web-1  |   path: '/app/.next/package.json'
> nti-web-web-1  | }
> nti-web-web-1 exited with code 1

Here is my Docker file:

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","run","dev"]
```

Here is my compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
```

Here is the scripts section of my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint --fix pages/ components/ hooks/ data/ __mocks__/ --ext .jsx,.js",
    "check": "pnpm run lint && pnpm jest",
    "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true next build",
    "analyze:server": "cross-env BUNDLE_ANALYZE=server next build",
    "analyze:browser": "cross-env BUNDLE_ANALYZE=browser next build",
    "test": "jest --coverage --coverageDirectory=output/coverage/jest"
  },
```

I have played around by changing the  working directory, changing file permissions (doesn't help, there is no .next folder after the docker build process), setting up volumes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely related to file permissions. Try adding a USER directive to your Dockerfile to run your commands as a non-root user.

```
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
USER node
CMD ["npm","run","dev"]
```

This should ensure that the user running the commands has the necessary permissions to access the files in the container.

Comment: There is no .next folder for any user to access.